# Как кастомизировать SearchBox?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Как можно сделать выдачу результатов так же, как История в SearchBox? То есть, выпадающий список при вводе текстовых данных. И, в дополнение, кастомизировать найденный список, как например ListView, добавив туда имейджи и другой контент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Используйте `AutoSuggestBox` вместо `SearchBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188204.aspx#searchbox). Для кастомизации выпадающего списка используйте `ItemTemplate`. В нем уже можете вставлять что угодно.

Comment: И снова вы меня спасли. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Horoko не за что.